# GET request for an image returns array of 3 matrix

Tags: r, image, matrix, get

I obtain the url of an user profile image using twitter API. GET request on the url obtained returns me an array of three matrix. Why there are three matrix? When I display each matrix using `image` function (s3 generic) I got  the image with different colour variation. Why I am not getting the actual image? I am new to all this. Please help.

```
    > imatrix <- content(GET("http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/454954067488288768/fU6NY-EI_normal.jpeg"))
    > class(imatrix)
    [1] "array"
    > image(imatrix[,,1])
```

[image][image]

Below Image is the actual image and above one is image displayed using `image`

Comment: Is there something like that we have to combine all the matrix in some manner to get the actual image

Comment: What packages are you using? I cannot find `content`...

Comment: You can find both GET and content in httr package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on where you want to go exactly you might have to look into other packages.

An easy example would be the `jpeg`-package:

```
library(jpeg)
link <- "http://www.starwars.com/the-force-awakens/images/share_1200x627.jpg"
download.file(link, destfile = "picture1.jpg", mode = "wb")

img <- readJPEG("picture1.jpg")

plot(1:2, type = "n")
rasterImage(img, 1, 1, 2, 2)
```

[image: Wonderful Picture]

(I'm sorry that I changed the picture, but found mine more beautiful... :) )

If you want to go deeper into image processing in R, you might want to look into the [imageR](http://www.r-bloggers.com/new-package-for-image-processing-in-r/), or the [`ripa`-package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ripa/index.html).

Lastly, you get the wrong colors in your picture, as the `image`-function plots the data using the `heat.colors` as specified with the `col` argument of the function.

I hope that points you in the right direction...

Comment: But I have a question. Is there any option for col argument to get the actual image.

Comment: To my understanding: the `image`-function tries to plot data with color, instead of printing an image (if that makes sense). It reads "Creates a grid of colored or gray-scale rectangles with colors corresponding to the values in z.", therefore I am not sure if that is possible